# .htaccess change the URL page with three conditions

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the url of my page like

```
http://localhost/Dynobase/my_computer.php?name=Deny-computer&type=computer&select=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/Dynobase/Deny-computer/computer/data/1
```

and to my htaccess file code like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/data/([[0-9]]+)$ /my_computer.php?name=$1&type=$2&select=$3 [L,NC]
```

but that I could actually error 404

maybe there is something wrong in my code. 
please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `/Dynobase/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Dynobase/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/data/([0-9]+)/?$ my_computer.php?name=$1&type=$2&select=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```